# Resources to learn ruby

Tags: php, ruby, jsp, ide

I am familiar with PHP and JSP. I am interested in learning ruby and would like some learning materials / resources / books to learn ruby. It would be better if the **material / books / resource compares Ruby with PHP or JSP**, as I prefer comparative learning. I would also like some suggestions for an IDE for ruby.

Comment: Read this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-ruby

Comment: i need some books that compares Ruby with PHP or JSP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never come across a book that bridges PHP to Ruby, sorry.

I am a Ruby beginner, and here is what I have bookmarked.

Interactive, try now:
https://try.ruby-lang.org/

Free resources:

- https://ruby-doc.org/
- https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/index.html
- https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/
- http://www.sapphiresteel.com/ruby-programming/The-Little-Book-Of-Ruby.html
- https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/

I'm not a fan of Why's Poignant Guide - I think the book's (attempts at) humor are distracting. He knows his stuff however. It might be to your liking, so:

- http://poignant.guide/

Recommended not-free book for beginner:

- [https://www.amazon.com/Well-Grounded-Rubyist-David-Black/dp/1933988657/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988657)

Programming challenges for practice:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692/where-can-you-find-funeducational-programming-challenges
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87657/what-are-some-good-programming-challenge-websites

I use SciTE for my Ruby interaction. It comes with the Ruby installer and does everything I need.

Answer (score 2):

Try this boook:

[rails-for-php-developers](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ndphpr/rails-for-php-developers)

a here is a good IDE for ruby [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)

Petr

Answer (score 0):

For dead-tree-edition books, I recommend the Pragmatic Programmer series for learning both Ruby & Rails. Online, the excellent reference docs at http://rubyonrails.org/documentation are my first go-to resource.

Comment: Pragmatic and Orielly have eBook versions of their books too, wich I keep on my laptop and desktop. The only downside to them is highlighting the pages makes a mess of my display.

Answer (score 0):

Use [VIM](http://www.vim.org/) & [Pickaxe](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby).